# How to change the text field value from fragment to button click event

Tags: android

Click on the button event.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
        Button result = view.findViewById(view.getId());
        textNo[R.id.t1].setText("2");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"클릭 : " + result.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

For example, is there a way to change the value of the first text view by clicking the first button?
There are countless buttons, so I gave resource id to each button and text
Now, for example, only 5 buttons and text views are given.

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            String textId = "t" + (i + 1);
            String buttonId = "b" + (i + 1);
            textNo[i] = view.findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier(textId, "id", getActivity().getPackageName()));
            buttonNo[i] = view.findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier(buttonId, "id", getActivity().getPackageName()));
```

When I press the button on the same line, I want to increase the number of text views located on it, but I kept trying, but I couldn't figure out how to do it in the fragment.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pl5y.png)

The outline of the XML code is as follows.

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/t1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/zero" />
```

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/b1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/Click"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle" />
```

It's my first time asking this question, so I'm very inexperienced, but if you tell me, I'll try harder.
I'm sorry that I'm not good at English.

Comment: Thought this isn't exactly how I would do it, you seem close. Add a click listener to your button that changes the text in the text view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
b1.setOnClickListener { 
    t1.text = "tttt"
}
```

If u have only a few buttons, you can write them in xml. For more, use horizontal RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `RecyclerView` in this case. Your method isn'n correct